# How to convert Kafka stream into Json format in Spark to parse the data in Java language

Tags: java, json, apache-spark

I am trying to parse the kafka Stream data into JSON format so that I can parse the real time incoming transnational data for required logic and further want to update it in Hbase table.

1.Incoming Stream of data would be in this format.

2.Where I need to extract `card_id`, `amount`, `postcode` and `transaction_dt`

> { “card_id”:348702330256514, “member_id”: 000037495066290, “amount”:
>   9084849, “pos_id”: 614677375609919, “postcode”: 33946,
>   “transaction_dt”: “11-02-2018 00:00:00” }

Created Kafka Consumer using code as listed below, however not sure how can I further process it into Jason via RDD.

```
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaSparkStreamingDemo").setMaster("local");

    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "100.xx.xxx.xxx:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "groupkafkaspark2");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", true);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("transactions-topic-verified");

    JavaDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));
```

I need to fetch the above 4 fields and then need to process on it, by looking into pre-created hbase table on similar data.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by using JSONObject and JSONPasrer class.